# no endpoint listening at local host

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I get an error on the client for my wcf service hosted by my console app. Now this works within my browser but not in my win forms which is a simple button textbox and label:

```
    public ServiceReference1.Service1Client testClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = testClient.GetData(Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text));
    }
```

The error I get is:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/hello that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Host console app code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        WebServiceHost host =
        new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1),
        binding,
        "http://localhost:8000/hello");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world service");
        Console.WriteLine("Press <RETURN> to end service");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Client App.cofig file code:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IService1">
                    <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                        messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                  <httpTransport></httpTransport>
                </binding>

            </customBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>

                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/hello" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WebHttpBinding_IService1" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.Service1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>

            </endpoint>

        </client>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you are exposing your service using webHttpBinding then its a RESTful service and you can access it using the HTTP GET/POST etc.. verbs. Try to browse to the URL http://localhost:8000/hello from your browser after the service is hosted and see what is the response you get in the browser.

Comment: If I browse to localhost:8000/hello I get an Endpoint not found. However if I browse to localhost:8000/hello/mystring I get the response I am looking for. The above should work fine the client should be able to write in the textbox and on button click the information is then sent and retrieved?

Comment: However it isnt it throws this error There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/hello that could accept the message. Which means the code `label1.Text = testClient.GetData(Convert.ToString(textBox1.Text));` isnt adding it to the end of the `/url`

Comment: If you are exposing it as a RESTful service then you need to append that as its the resource name and accessing it using SOAP is not the right way. If you want to access it via soap then define an endpoint that has BasicHttpBinding.

Comment: In your console app you are using WebHttpBinding rather use BasicHttpBinding when hosting your service

Comment: Yes because I want it to be restful...?

Comment: In that case you would not need a client side config file and no service reference on your client side to access it. You can access the service using HttpWebRequest class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access a RESTful service you can use the below code:

```
private string UseHttpWebApproach<T>(string serviceUrl, string resourceUrl, string method, T requestBody)
        {
            string responseMessage = null;
            var request = WebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.ContentType = "application/xml";
                request.Method = method;
            }    

            if(method == "POST" && requestBody != null)
            {                    
                byte[] requestBodyBytes = ToByteArrayUsingJsonContractSer(requestBody);                
                request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                    postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);

            }

            if (request != null)
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                        responseMessage = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                }
            }
            return responseMessage;
        }
```

ServiceUrl : `http://localhost:8000`

ResourceUrl : `hello/yourstring`

Method : `GET`

RequestBody: Null

Comment: Yes, you can use the code in your client app to invoke a RESTful service